# Show name of the selected file

Tags: javascript, php, file

I want to show the file name after user has selected a file to upload. Here the web site where I need this function: [MB@ Consulting - Upload File Page](https://www.mbaconsulting.it/cloud-upload/)

I have customized css and php file as follows:

```
<div class="inputfile-box">
    <label for="file">

        <input type="file" id="file" class="inputfile" name="file"  onchange="fileSelected(this);" />

        <span id="file-name" class="file-box"></span>

        <span class="file-button"><i class="fa fa-folder-open"></i>
          Scegli file
        </span>

    </label>

    <label class="custom-file-start-upload">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" onclick="startUploading()" />
        <i class="fa fa-play"></i> Upload
    </label>
</div>
```

The CSS is :

```
// Hide input old style
input[type="file"] {
    display: none;
}

input[type="submit"] {
    display: none;
}

// Style of label
.custom-file-start-upload {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    cursor: pointer;
}    

.file-box, .file-button {
    cursor: pointer;
}

.file-box-send, .file-button-send {
    cursor: pointer;
}

 .custom-file-start-upload {
    background-color: #62ea62;
}

.inputfile-box {
  position: relative;
    width:100%;
    max-width: 360px;
}

.inputfile {
  display: none;
}

.container {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}

.file-box {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 5px 0px 5px 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: calc(2rem - 2px);
    min-height: 36px;
}

.file-button {
  background: #d52727;
  padding: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

I took the code for this function from another page ([Example](https://jsfiddle.net/rjurado/hnf0zhy1/4/))
Working in demo page, but not working in my website !
I try to add this JS :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function fileSelected(target) {
        document.getElementById("file-name").innerHTML = target.files[0].name;
    }
</script>
```

But the file name is not displayed in the separate field "file-name".

Comment: As @Saral mentioned in answer, check if `fileSelected` function already exists (the easiest way with `alert(fileSelected)` or `console.log(fileSelected)`). if `!= undefined` than rename that func and voila.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JavaScript code is working but the JavaScript of some plugin in your website surprisingly has a function with the same name as you are using in your `onchange` event in your HTML. You need to change the function name to something unique.

```
<input type="file" id="file" class="inputfile" name="file" onchange="fileIsSelected(this);">
```

I've changed the function name to `fileIsSelected` here. You also need to change the name in JavaScript.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function fileIsSelected(target) 
    {
        document.getElementById("file-name").innerHTML = target.files[0].name;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: @DavidePica Simply change the function name as I've shown to you in your HTML and JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

To solve my problem I added the second function in the intput field, so it has both the old and the new one running (onchange="fileSelected() 
 and  fileIsSelected(this) ).

This :

```
<input type="file" id="file" class="inputfile" name="file"  onchange="fileSelected(); fileIsSelected(this);" />
```

and use JS :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function fileIsSelected(target) 
    {
        document.getElementById("file-name").innerHTML = target.files[0].name;
    }
</script>
```

Thanks :)